# ModelState validation on RedirectToAction in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to implement `ModelState.AddModelError` on `RedirectToAction` in MVC. Currently, I am not getting error message. Can anyone please help me?

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{  
     var HList = hDetails.HTrackerList().Where(x => x.AccId == user.AccountID && x.UserId == user.Id).Select(y=>y.HorseId).ToList();
     var datainList = HList.Contains(model.HorseId);

     if(!datainList)
     {            
         hDetails.InsertHorse(model);
     }
     else
     {
        ModelState.AddModelError("datainList", "Horse is already exist. Do you want to update it?");
     }
}

return RedirectToAction("Home");
```

**In the View:**

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("datainList")
```

Comment: return `View`, do not redirect, if you want to see error message. `return View();`

Comment: You are redirecting - `ModelState` is only applicable in the current method when you return the view. One option would be to send that error message as query string value, or alternatively add it to `TempData` (and then get it again in the GET method and add it to `ModelState`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, can you please show me how to send it through query string

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Home", new { error = "Horse is already exist .... ");` and then add a `string error` parameter in that method. But in the get method, I would just display that in the view as some text, because its not really a `ModelState` (validation) error

Comment: @StephenMuecke, you are right. This is not actually modelstate error. Sorry to ask you, please show me how to do this in view part as well.

Comment: Well you could add a `string Message` property to your view model, or you could just use `ViewBag` (e.g. `ViewBag.Message = error;`) and then just add it to the view - `<p class="message">@Model.Message</p>` (or `@ViewBag.Message`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you so much. Small doubt, can I implement alert message here because If user click on Yes then it will redirect to edit page else will got main view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177728/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mvc).

Comment: @MVC Don't know why you people always post incomplete code. What's wrong to post the complete necessary code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your ontroller class:**

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult TestMethod()
   {
       if(ModelState.IsValid)
       {  
         var HList = hDetails.HTrackerList().Where(x => x.AccId == user.AccountID && x.UserId == user.Id).Select(y=>y.HorseId).ToList();
         var datainList = HList.Contains(model.HorseId);

         if(!datainList)
         {            
            hDetails.InsertHorse(model);
         }
         else
         {
            TempData["datainListError"] = "Horse is already exist. Do you want to update it?";
         }
       }

      return RedirectToAction("Home");
   }
}
```

**Then in the Home Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       if(TempData.ContainsKey("datainListError"))
       {
          ViewBag.ErrorMessage = TempData["datainListError"].ToString();
       }

      return View();

    }

}
```

Then in the Index View:

```
@if(ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null)
{
   <div class="alert alert-danger">@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</div>
}
```

Comment: Great to hear that!